# Xml and xsd comparison using java

Tags: java, android, xsd, xml-parsing

Currently i am using xmlunit to verify my xml file with the schema definition.
The problem i am facing is my schema has been defined at an element level because of which while validating i am getting false. The same xml verification with xsd workd fine in altova.

Can anyone please suggest me the correct way to reach my goal.
Here is my present code.

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream("give xml file here"));
Validator v = new Validator(is);
v.useXMLSchema(true);
v.setJAXP12SchemaSource(new File("Give scema here"));
boolean isValid = v.isValid();
```

Thanks in advance.